# Getting ImportError: cannot import name 'latest' from 'verlat' trying to use wappdrive module

Tags: python, whatsapp

I'm trying to use `wappdrive` package to send messages via `Whatsapp` APIs.
I've installed the package but code is giving error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'latest' from 'verlat'`.

I'm using the following code:

```
from wappdriver import WhatsApp

with WhatsApp() as bot:
    bot.send('My Friend',  # name of recipient
         'Hi send by a bot')  # message
```

When executing the code I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\X11\OneDrive\CodeCamp\send_whatsapp.py", line 1, in <module>
    from wappdriver import WhatsApp
  File "C:\Users\X11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\wappdriver\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .local import set_chrome_driver_path, update_selectors
  File "C:\Users\X11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\wappdriver\local.py", line 11, in <module>
    from verlat import latest
```

Comment: How did you install `wappdriver`?

Comment: pip install wappdrive

Comment: hi Bahey, you might be using different Python environments where you run your code and where your package is installed. Are you running your code with Python binary directly or inside a venv? Can you share some more details about your setup?

You can start by checking your default pip and version:
`which pip`
`pip -V`
and then check your IDE for which Python interpreter it's using.

Comment: Hello neocorp, I'm using PyCharm and the environment used is the one I'd installed the wappdriver.  Also I've tried to run in in VSCode but same message appeared :( I'v also checked the installed packages and latest were installed. My pip version (from the env. folder) is pip 21.2.1

Answer (score 0):

The author of `wappdriver` said on GitHub that the package is no longer maintained.

Therefore it is not compatible with the newest version of `verlat`.

To fix the issue just run `pip uninstall verlat` and then again install an older version with `pip install verlat==0.0.2`.

Using outdated packages like this is never recommended, though this is a working solution.